# Has basemap become outdated?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I'm currently coding Python 3.6 and using basemap 1.0.7. I am running into problems with the toolkit, which seems to be because it is using now-deprecated functions of matplotlib. Just to name a few:

- "*MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: axes.hold is deprecated*"
- "*MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The get_axis_bgcolor function was deprecated in version 2.0. Use get_facecolor instead.*"

I can't follow the guides, due to limited/missing functionality.

Questions tagged with matplotlib-basemap seem to be somewhat active. Am I missing something? Are people still having success with basemap? If not, are there some alternatives available? I've looked at plotly, vincent, and geoplotlib. I've run into deprecation errors using the latter two, and I'd like something completely open, not requiring sign-up as Plotly.

Comment: Last basemap was released in 2013. I guess you have new matplotlib 2.0 which introduce that some functions are depreciated but they are still used by basemap 1.0.7.

Comment: However last version is 1.0.8.

Comment: That is a correct assumption regarding my module versions. I appreciate your elaboration - thank you